# File Manager for a shared network drive using just Angular

Tags: angular, file-manager

Is there a way to build an Angular project with no backend dependency, which gives you access to all the files and folders of a particular network drive so that you can see all the files on your browser and launch them ?

I have over 50000 files in a folder located in a network drive shared with me. I want to display all the files on my browser and allow access.

How can I implement this ?